# encryption method against man in the middle attack

Tags: encryption, cryptography, man-in-the-middle

Let's say there are 3 computers: Alice, Bob, Carol. Carol is network provider, so everything from Alice to Bob and vice versa passes through Carol. Carol can modify messages between Alice and Bob. Is there any algorithm or method for secure communication between Alice and Bob, even if Carol can modify packages? For Diffie-Hellman I found [this](http://www.rsa.com/rsalabs/node.asp?id=2248):

> Roughly speaking, the basic idea is as follows. Prior to execution of
>   the protocol, the two parties Alice and Bob each obtain a
>   public/private key pair and a certificate for the public key. During
>   the protocol, Alice computes a signature on certain messages, covering
>   the public value ga mod p. Bob proceeds in a similar way. Even though
>   Carol is still able to intercept messages between Alice and Bob, she
>   cannot forge signatures without Alice's private key and Bob's private
>   key. Hence, the enhanced protocol defeats the man-in-the-middle
>   attack.

Can anyone explain with example?

Edit:
A is client, and B is server, A uses login/password to authenticate.

Comment: @torateff you should mark Thomas Pornin's answer as right answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need a **definition**. Namely, what is "Bob" in Alice's view ? If "Bob" is "whoever responds" then Carol would make a nice Bob -- in that case, there is no real attack, just Alice talking to "someone" who happens to be Carol.

If there *is* a definite notion of Bobness that Alice can use, then there are algorithms which build on that. That's how [SSL works](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20803/how-does-ssl-work). Imagine that you are Alice, Bob is a Web site that you know *by name* (e.g. "www.paypal.com"), and Carol is your Evil ISP. You do not want to talk to just *anybody*, you want to talk to a specific Bob/server that has a name. [Public key certificates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key_certificate) can use *signatures* to give you some guarantee over the binding between the name ("Bob", aka "www.paypal.com") and a public key: the guarantee provided by the whole system is that a given public key is really "owned" by an entity who bears the name "www.paypal.com", where "owning" means "having exclusive control of the corresponding private key", and in a way that Carol *cannot* obtain a similar guarantee.

Once there is a known server's public key, the key exchange can be protected against MitM. Again, see how it is done with SSL.

In the case of X.509 certificates, Alice must have an *a priori* knowledge of a root certificate authority public key (here "trust anchor"). For another model, consider [SSH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell). Here, we *assume* that Alice could establish, at some point, a Carol-less connection to Bob (or a connection that Carol did not bother to alter). Then, Alice *remembers* Bob's key, and uses it again for all subsequent connections. That's how SSH usually works: for the first connection, the client requests explicit user confirmation, then stores the public key in Alice's `.ssh/known_hosts` file. Ideally, for the first confirmation, Alice would verify with some out-of-band mechanism the server's public key (its fingerprint) before accepting it the first time (e.g. by making a phone call to the server sysadmin, and checking with him the key fingerprint).

Comment: In my case Alice is me, Bob - is skype server, Carol is my ISP, I wanted to know can my ISP read my messages. Beside skype, if I build my own instant messaging service, what steps must I do to keep secure communication?

Answer (score 1):

Possible answer:
when you communicated with through secured connection such as SSH, SCP, SFTP, and the likes, and as long your linux box (client) is not compromised, you basically are safe from "man in the middle" attack. TLS/SSL protocol is considered to be secure.
Self-signed certificate if you signed it yourself, it's safe, too.

See also https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/6437/how-would-one-fully-protect-himself-against-man-in-the-middle-attacks

Comment: You are safe from man-in-the-middle attacks *if you check the server key*, i.e. don't click through SSL warnings with HTTPS, check the server's public key fingerprint with SSH.